# SetThemingColor of hidden elements

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do i set the theming of components of a model which is hidden:
If i not using the hideModel function everthing is working perfect, but if the model is hided i get an error 2 => BAD_DATA = 2,

```
this.viewerComponent.viewer.hideModel(this.viewerComponent.viewer.model);
```

The following things i already tried out:

```
this.viewerComponent.viewer.getHiddenModels()[0].setThemingColor(idArray[0], color, true);


this.viewerComponent.viewer.setThemingColor(idArray[0], color, this.viewerComponent.viewer.getHiddenModels()[0]);
```

This is not working for sure, since the model of the viewer will be `null` after hiding

```
this.viewerComponent.viewer.setThemingColor(idArray[0], color, this.viewerComponent.viewer.model());
```

Viewer Version 7

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `viewer.hideModel` is a bit of a misnomer because it doesn't just hide the model, it actually **unloads** it. If you want to hide the model while still keeping all its data in memory, you might be able to achieve a similar result by calling `viewer.hide(viewer.model.getRootId())`. This will hide (or "ghost", if you have "ghosting" enabled; see below) the individual elements of the model while still keeping them in memory, so you can still configure properties like the theming color.

[image]